# Google Sign-in in ASP.Net MVC Application to use Gmail API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have followed the tutorial from [**here**](http://peleyal.blogspot.in/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-with-google-openid-and-oauth.html) to Sign-in with Google and access GMail API within an ASP.Net MVC  application.

But at this line my program is stuck, i mean there is no response, i suppose from google server.

```
var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppAuthFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I have no idea why it is taking time to Authorize the user request.

Comment: what is your target framework set to? What type of application did you make in the developer console? I have seen this before i just cant remember what it was.

Comment: target framework in .Net 4 and its MVC 4 application.

Comment: You created a "Client ID for web application" correct?

Comment: yes i have created that, configured return uri too

Comment: Do you know how just login to Gmail having login and password assigned to variables already?

Comment: @Yoda i didnt get your question.....anyways....this question is solved....plz look at my answer...thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The main issue is with the `async` and `await` keywords. These
  keywords though supported in VS2010 as **CTP**, don't actually work in VS
  2010 with .Net Framework 4.
- These keywords are released finally with .Net Framework 4.5 and
  fully support VS 2012.
- **Hence to make this work, I have to port my solution to VS 2012.**

Pretty simple solution, i guess, i should have figured out earlier :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your particular issue is. I've used the following to access the Gmail API.

```
// Create OAuth Credential.
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    },
    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
    "me",
    CancellationToken.None).Result;
// Create the service.
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Draft Sender",
});
ListDraftsResponse draftsResponse = service.Users.Drafts.List("me").Execute();
IList<Draft> drafts = draftsResponse.Drafts;
```

Comment: There may be an issue with the current stable Auth library, try this pre-release one:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication

Comment: What Auth library are you using?

Comment: i m using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2

Comment: Try using Google.Apis.Auth -Version 1.8.1 there seems to be issues with the 1.8.2 version.